# Whole form is submitted in onchange event , want only aparticular field to be submitted and fetch the value from server

Tags: jsf, onchange

When i use the below change event and onchange function , the whole form is rendering and reset to intial value , could you please advise on this.

**Code snippet :**

```
  <h:inputText id="txtInjIncDiag" tabindex="5"
                            styleClass="inputText" style="width:65px";
   value="#{ReportBeanPage.mirAF.codeone}" maxlength="7"
   valueChangeListener    ="#{ReportBeanPage.handlelistener}"
   onchange="return func_1(this, event);" immediate="true"  
   onkeydown="return noCTRL(event)"
   onkeypress="javascript:toUpperCase();"
>
```

Return function in javascript:

```
function func_1(thisObj, thisEvent) {
thisObj.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: @BalusC : We are having JSP , so we are unable to use AJAX .I want to send the value through Listener but the whole page is refreshing ! Please advise.

Comment: You should have clarified that in the question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. JSP in JSF is deprecated since years. No one would expect someone asking about JSP these days without explicitly mentioning it in the question.